# Помогите с index.php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, скрипт

у меня есть html-фаил, нужно что бы он открывался как PHP скрипт(index.php)

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCC7A8;
}

div {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  padding: 15mm 15mm 15mm 25mm;
  margin: 25px auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 1.2
}

p {
  text-indent: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <center><b>A K T<br/>на возврат товара</b><br/>
    <br>Дата составления акта: «___»______________2018 г.<br>
    </br>от Покупателя: _______________________________________
    <center><i><sub>Юридическое название организации</i></sub><br></center>
    </br>
    Адрес Покупателя: ____________________________________
    <center><i><sub>Фактический адрес доставки</sub></i></center>
  </center>
  <p><b>Дата возврата:_______________________________</b></p>

  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="18" width="100%" height="230">

    <tr>
      <td><b>Наименование товара</b></td>
      <td><b>Количество</b></td>
      <td><b>Причина возврата</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><br/></td>
      <td><br/></td>
      <td><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><br/><br/></td>
      <td><br/><br/></td>
      <td><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><br/><br/></td>
      <td><br/><br/></td>
      <td><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <p style="text-indent:100px"><b>Представитель от покупателя</b></p>
  <p>Фамилия И.О.__________________ Подпись _____________Дата ____________</p>
  <p style="text-indent:100px"><b>Акт принял водитель-экспедитор</b></p>
  <p>Фамилия И.О.__________________ Подпись _____________Дата ____________</p>
  <p style="text-indent:100px"><b>Кладовщик принял, заключение</b></p>
  <p>Заключение: ______________________________________________________________________</p>
  <p>Фамилия И.О.__________________ Подпись _____________Дата ____________</p><br/>
  <p>Проверил оператор:</p>
  <p>Дата : ____________________</p>
  <p>Подпись : ____________________</p>
</div><br/>
<div>
  <center><b>A K T<br/>
      списание товара</b><br/>
    <br>Дата составления акта: «___»______________2018 г.<br>
    </br>
    от Покупателя: _______________________________________
    <center><i><sub>Юридическое название организации</i></sub><br></center>
    </br>
    Адрес Покупателя: ____________________________________
    <center><i><sub>Фактический адрес доставки</sub></i></center>
  </center>
  <br/>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%" height="50">

    <tr>
      <td><b>Наименование товара</b></td>
      <td><b>Количество</b></td>
      <td><b>Причина списания</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Проверил оператор:</p>
  <p>Дата : ____________________</p>
  <p>Подпись : ____________________</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто надо разобраться с терминами:

`html-фаил != index.php`.

HTML-файл это `index.html`

PHP-файл это    `index.php`

Собсна внутри `PHP-файла` содержатся `PHP-скрипты`(а еще правильнее - `инструкции`). Чтобы их выполнить, надо пропустить файл через `PHP-интерпретатор`.

`PHP-Интерпретатор` работает с `PHP-инструкциями`  которые могут храниться не только в файлах.

Обычно, вам достаточно поднять у себя какой нибудь сервер, и там в комплекте все входит. Сидите и пишите свои `php-инструкции` в `php-файле` и запускайте их с помощью `php-интерпретатора`.